# Why does this regular expression evaluate to false in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a string that is 0-9 digits, no other characters.

This is alerting me with a "false" value:

```
var regex = new RegExp('^[\d]{0,9}$');
alert(regex.test('123456789'));
```

These return true, and I understand why  (The ^ and $ indicate that the whole string needs to match, not just a match within the string) :

```
var regex = new RegExp('[\d]{0,9}');
alert(regex.test('123456789'));
```

-

```
var regex = new RegExp('[\d]{0,9}');
alert(regex.test('12345678934341243124'));
```

and this returns true:

```
var regex = new RegExp('^[\d]{0,9}');
alert(regex.test('123456789'));
```

So why, when I add the "$" at the end would this possibly be failing?

And what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: you don't need to enclose `\d` inside square brackets unless you also want to match against other possible characters.

Comment: PS: you need to escage the backslashes when using string literals: `\\d`.

Comment: @sp00m: but it isn't a string literal, it's a regex literal. David: the one you reports `false` gives me `true` (running ECMAScript ECMA-262).

Comment: Easiest solution: Don't use `new Regex()` at all; just use an inline regular expression -- `var regex = /^\d{0,9}$/;` Much simpler. Only use `new Regex()` if you want an expression that you can dynamically define.

Comment: @Jongware It IS a string literal. RegExp literals are surrounded with `/`, not quotes.

Comment: @Jongware You're wrong, is a string literal. A regex literal would have been `/[\d]{0,9}/`, OP would then not need to escape backslashes.

Comment: And the reason both work for me is, what? A bad implementation in ECMAScript? Note that David's *other* examples **do** work.

Comment: @Jongware Because the other examples are matching `d` 0 times.

Comment: @Jongware `new RegExp('[\d]{0,9}')` actually generates the regex `[d]{0,9}`, which gets matched due to the *"**zero** or more"* cardinality (`{0,9}`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use

```
var regex = new RegExp('^[\d]{0,9}$');
```

syntax, you'll get regex as

```
/^[d]{0,9}$/
```

**Note the `\d` is turned into `d`.**

This regex `/^[d]{0,9}$/` will match only the `d` zero to nine times.

`RegExp` uses string to define regex, the `\` is also used as escape symbol in the string, so `\` in `\d` is considered as the escape character.

Escape the `\` by preceding it with another `\`.

```
var regex = new RegExp('^[\\d]{0,9}$');
```

I'll recommend you to use regex literal syntax rather than the confusing `RegExp` syntax.

```
var regex = /^\d{0,9}$/;
```

---

**EDIT:**

The reason you get `true` when using `var regex = new RegExp('^[\d]{0,9}');` is because the regex implies that the string should start with **any** number of `d` include zero to nine. So, event when the string does not starts with `d` the condition is stratified because of `0` as the minimum no of occurrences.

You might want to check if the string starts with one to nine digits.

```
var regex = /^\d{1,9}$/;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I knew I had to be overlooking something obvious.

Comment: @David Another problem is that you're using `{0,9}` which means no match of the previous group `\d` is also allowed, so you're getting the weird results when using regex

Answer (score 2):

You should use the regular expression literal (without quotes and using the beginning and ending slashes) when defining the RegExp object. This is the recommended approach when the regular expression will remain constant, meaning it does not need to be compiled every time it is used. This gives you the desired result:

```
var regex = new RegExp(/^[\d]{0,9}$/);
```

Answer (score -5):

Because $ means End of line, and your string does not have an end of line as last character

May be you are looking for "\z"

Comment: `$` means "end of string" if you're not in multi-line mode

Comment: Hum, i see, i come from ruby and it is diferent :(